# Export single Eclipse Perspective and Settings

Tags: eclipse, ide, perspective

I customized my Eclipse for a special Latex Perspective and saved this perspective as "MyLatex". I even added shortcuts in my texlipse preferences, so that I can type "tab"+strg+space to insert a table.

Now I would like to offer this to friends. I found out that I can use Export->General->Settings, but this exports ALL perspectives.

Is there any way to export only the perspective "myLatex" and the texlipse editor templates?

Best regards
Philipp

Comment: I discovered: to export the texlipse templates there is an export button in the settings.

Comment: Since perspectives are something of personal flavor, i decided just to give my customizations as suggestions. http://philippandre.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/optimize-texlipse-for-advanced-latex-writers/

Answer (score 11):

There exists another way to do this.

**[Share Eclipse perspective layouts across multiple workspaces](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/share-eclipse-perspective-layouts-across-multiple-workspaces/)**

> To save your perspective, select Window > Save Perspective As… from
>   the application menu. A dialog should popup (shown below), prompting
>   you for a perspective name. Enter a name  that you’ll remember, eg. My
>   Java or Debug Jack. Click Ok once you’ve entered a new name.
>
> Note: You can choose to overwrite one of the default perspectives, eg.
>   Java, without fear. However, I prefer to leave these intact, so always
>   choose a new name, but you can choose whatever works for you.
>
> [image]
>
> Now you can go through the normal routine of exporting the preferences
>   to a properties file via File > Export > General > Preferences. Then
>   import the same  file in another workspace via File > Import > General > Preferences. All you now have to do is switch over to the perspective you saved and all your layout settings will be restored.
>   If you overwrote one of the default perspectives, you may have to
>   select Window > Reset Perspective… to restore the saved settings.
>
> If you’ve chosen to create a new perspective, be sure to point your
>   Run/Debug settings to the new perspective under Window > Preferences >
>   Run/Debug > Perspectives. For example, if you made a new perspective
>   based on the Debug perspective, then you’ll need to change references
>   to the Debug perspective to the My Debug for launchers you use.

Comment: I tried on Eclipse 4.8.0 (Photon) and it works perfect, also with Preferences and Working Set.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a nice way to export/import one perspective from eclipse, but maybe try the following:

open this file -

`workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml`

and copy the part that relates to your new perspective to the same file for the users you want to share it to. If this doesn't work you may have to replace the entire file in their workspace with your one.

Comment: Hard to believe that there is now way to do this in a more usefull manner. But you seem right, all blogposts i found do refere to this file as well.

Comment: The path has changed in more recent versions of eclipse: `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`

Comment: yes, it's a pity that eclipse does not offer to export/import all user settings.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to copy from one workspace to another

> .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench